# Lightning Components in Managed Package

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package, namespace

**Background**

We are developing an app where we use lightning components.

**Issue**

When are trying to package the components, package manager returns an error referencing to some custom fields that are not found in the package. This is because when we created the namespace, it added a prefix in every custom metadata.

**Workarounds**

1. Put the prefix in every custom fields and object in the component, controller and helper code.
2. Get the prefix from a custom metadata type and build dynamically the metadata names. It works fine for the Component Controller and Helper. But we cannot set the prefix dynamically in the component page.

**Expected workaround**

We want to get the prefix from a custom metadata type because we have several environments and it change between them. So we can discard the 1st workaround.

Then, if we want to use custom fields dynamically in the component, we think that the only way is to use a DTO class in the controller.

> What is the best practice to use the prefix namespace in Lightning Components?

**Code Samples**

```
<!-- parentComponet.cmp -->
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" controller="ExampleHelper" access="global">
<aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}" />
...
<aura:attribute name="prefix" type="String" access="private" default="prefix__" />
...
<c:child_1 aura:id="child_1" prefix="{!v.prefix}" settingExample="..." />
<c:child_2 aura:id="child_2" prefix="{!v.prefix}" objectExample="..." />
...
</aura:component>

<!-- parentComponentController.js -->
({
   doInit: function(cmp, event, helper){
    helper.getPrefix();
   ...
   },
   ...
})
<!-- parentComponentHelper.js -->
({
 getPrefix: function(){
   ...
   action.getCall...
   ...
   cmp.set('v.prefix', e.getReturnValue());
 });
})

-- COMPONENT CHILD --
<!-- child_1.cmp -->
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="prefix" type="String" access="global" />
    <aura:attribute name="settingExample" type="Object" access="global" />
    {!v.settingExample.nameExample__c} //NOT VALID WITH PREFIX
    {!v.settingExample.[prefix]+'.'+nameExample__c} //NOT WORKING
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Each object can have many fields or just single field, that you wan to display?

Comment: Each object can have many fields.

Comment: Having DTO class(Wrapper class) is the best way you could make the code work in the different namespace based on environment.

Comment: Thank you @Praveen, I think also this is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to have a Utility/Base component which can be extended by any component.

`Utility.cmp`

```
<aura:component extensible="true">
        <aura:attribute 
            name="packagePrefix" 
            type="String" 
            default="" 
            description="Package prefix is calculated by the init method."/>
        <aura:attribute 
            name="labelPrefix" 
            type="String" 
            default="c" 
            description="The label prefix, calculated from the package prefix."/>

        <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.myInit}"/>
</aura:component>
```

`UtilityController.js`

```
({
    myInit:function(component, event, helper) {
        // make server side call to get package prefix
        component.set("v.packagePrefix", "packagePrefixName");
        component.set("v.labelPrefix", "packagePrefixLabel");
    }
})
```

---

With extending any of your component with Utility, you get access to the package prefix.

`ExampleComponent.cmp`

```
<aura:component extends="c:Utility">
    packagePrefix : {v.packagePrefix} <br/>
    labelPrefix : {v.labelPrefix}
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul. This is awesome way to have the prefix in the component but how can we use the prefix in each sobject field dynamically?{!v.settingExample.nameExample__c} //NOT VALID WITH PREFIX
{!v.settingExample.[prefix]+'.'+nameExample__c} //NOT WORKING

Comment: Prefix would be `namespace__`, to access a field value from object's instance is `{!Account['namespace__customField__c']}`. Based on this hypothesis, try: `{!v.settingExample[prefix + 'customField__c']}`

Comment: @RahulSharma dynamically field expression as suggested above will not work in Lightning Components.

Comment: @RahulSharma as Praveen is saying, it not works in LC. Compiler returns an error because expect an integer instead of a string: {!v.settingExample[0]}

Comment: I think you need to follow specific pattern in code and maybe generate a object or list in client side?

Answer (score 0):

I think of the following.

You can create a new component that accepts the prefix and the fields to be displayed.

The following code may contain some bug, it is more an idea than something functional.

```
<!-- componentParent -->
<c:prefixComponent prefix="{!v.prefix}" item="nameExample__c" value="{!v.settingExample}" />

<!--prefixComponent.cmp -->
 <aura:component>
  <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}" />
  <aura:attribute name="prefix" type="text" />
  <aura:attribute name="item" type="text" />
  <aura:attribute name="value" type="text" />

  {!v.value}
 </aura:component>

<!-- Controller.js -->
({
doInit:function(cmp, evt, helper){
var prefix = cmp.get('v.prefix');
var item = cmp.get('v.item');
let result = '';
let elements = item.split('.');


element.forEach(item, i){
  if(i != 0){
    result += '.';
  }
  result += prefix+item;
}
let resultPrefix = value+'.'+result;
cmp.set('v.value', cmp.get(resultPrefix));

}
})
```